# Making a simple camera app

Tags: android, camera, temporary-files

I made a simple camera app that was working just fine the other day. Now i tried it again today and i keep getting a nullpointer on the file. I used breakpoints in my code to see what goes wrong.

```
filefotoFile = maakFotoBestand();
```

.

```
    public File maakFotoBestand() throws IOException
{
    //maak een unieke filename aan aan de hand van een timestamp en zet de file storage klaar
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format (new Date());
    String imgFileName = "IMAGE_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    //sla de foto op in het geheugen aan de hand van de genoemde namen
    File image = File.createTempFile(imgFileName, ".JPG", storageDirectory);

    //Zeg de app waar de foto staat
    imageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return image;
}
```

He seems to stop at the line File image = File.create.........

He already returns at that line. And if I than look at the content of image its NULL Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT===================================================
Here is the entire code and the logcat

```
package nl.compict.cameraapp;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener
{

private static final int ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP = 1;
private ImageView mFotoCapturedImageView;
private String imageFileLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFotoCapturedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView01);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();

    //Roep de Android Camera App aan met de actie om een foto te maken
    callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    //
    File fotoFile = null;
    try
    {
        fotoFile = maakFotoBestand();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        //geef de error weer als die plaatsvind
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //roep de CameraApp nog een keer aan en onthoud het bestand dat is aangemaakt
    callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(fotoFile));

    //Start een activity met een request code zodat je die wee kan afvangen en wacht op een resultaat
    startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    //Kijk of de request en resultcode overeenkomen met wat wij willen doen
    if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        //Haal de foto op aan de hand van de imageFileLocation
        Bitmap fotoCaptureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFileLocation);
        mFotoCapturedImageView.setImageBitmap(fotoCaptureBitmap);
    }
}

public File maakFotoBestand() throws IOException
{
    //maak een unieke filename aan aan de hand van een timestamp en zet de file storage klaar
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format (new Date());
    String imgFileName = "IMAGE_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    //sla de foto op in het geheugen aan de hand van de genoemde namen
    File image = File.createTempFile(imgFileName, ".JPG", storageDirectory);

    //Zeg de app waar de foto staat
    imageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return image;
}
}
```

Logcat

```
01-20 10:50:24.749 2398-2398/nl.compict.cameraapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: nl.compict.cameraapp, PID: 2398
                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
                                                                    at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:452)
                                                                    at nl.compict.cameraapp.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:58)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: share complete log cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code, it works perfectly, you just need to add permissions inside your manifest :

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

But I had to add a button to trigger the capture, like this :

Inside your layout :

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="59dp" />
```

Inside your class :

```
...
buttonTakePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
...
@Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(v == buttonTakePicture) {
            Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();

            //Roep de Android Camera App aan met de actie om een foto te maken
            callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            //
            File fotoFile = null;
            try {
                fotoFile = maakFotoBestand();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //geef de error weer als die plaatsvind
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //roep de CameraApp nog een keer aan en onthoud het bestand dat is aangemaakt
            callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(fotoFile));

            //Start een activity met een request code zodat je die wee kan afvangen en wacht op een resultaat
            startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Stupid, the camera permission was gone, must have accidentily deleted it. thnx :D

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have external storage available to your app. Other but least possibility is that your app dont have permission to to access external storage. put some check blocks for permissions and storage availability.